# Uploading multiple images with React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I am working on upload multiple pictures functionality.

```
let imageFile : any = [];
const images = payload.multipleImages;
for(let i = 0; i < images.interior.length ; i++){
    imageFile.push(images[i]);
}
payload.multipleImages = imageFile;
console.log('images',payload.multipleImages);
const data = { ...values, ...payload };
dispatch(vehicleActions.postVehicle(data));
```

I have tried to send multiple images in array format in API but instead array of binary images `multipleImages: [(binary) (binary)]` it is sending `multipleImages[]: (binary)` it twice for 2 images. I have also tried `multipleImages: [...data.multipleImages]` but i am getting the same result.

```
const url = `/vehicles/dealer/vehicle/add`;
return axiosClient().post(url,
 {
  price : data.price,
  manufactureYear : data.manufactureYear,
  kiloMeters : data.kiloMeters,
  plateNumber : data.plateNumber,
  fuelType : data.fuelType,
  multipleImages: data.multipleImages,
 }
);
```

I expect it to allow me to send the array of binary images.

Comment: What "same result" are you getting?

Comment: I am getting multipleImages[]: (binary) twice for 2 images, if i upload three images i am getting it three times.